# CSS vertical-align:middle but not middle

Tags: html, css

I have an inline-block element (span) inside an anchor which has a 40px height. I try to vertically center span but it gets a position that more likely close to the bottom. It is not at the middle. How can i really vertically center that span?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amLx9b2w/2/)

HTML

```
<a>Admin<span></span></a>
```

CSS

```
a{
    display:block;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    line-height:40px;
}

span{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:50%;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: its actually at the vertical center..See this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/amLx9b2w/3/)..Here i have changed the `line-height` to 100px just to test..

Comment: But i have to use a line-height of 40px

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
a{ line-height: 40px; }
```

use

```
a{ height: 40px; }
```

And then center with

```
a:before {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/amLx9b2w/4/)